# Service Reference fails to deserialize correctly and puts null in fields (asp.net to asp.net)

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wse

So i'm having a weird issue with my service reference in my VS2010 project that i can't really figure out.

Any time i rebuild the soap service that the service reference is attached to i can no longer deserialize the data from one of the methods. All of the other methods work but one in particular just gets filled with null/default values instead of the correct values. I can confirm that the web service is still returning good data and looks to be in the correct format. Once i update the service reference it all works again until i rebuild.

When i go and look at the diff of the structure i see that the following files are now different:

- Configuration.svcinfo
- Configuration91.svcinfo
- Reference.cs
- Reference.svcmap
- MyService.disco
- MyService.wsdl

When i look in the wsdl it looks almost like the fields were re-ordered. But i don't see how that is possible.

Here is the header information for my web service

```
[WebService(Namespace = http://myservice/)]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[Policy("ServerPolicy")]
```

Anyone know why this is happening with each rebuild?

EDIT: Here is an example.

For example here is a random change that was made, this class was not changed but only recompiled:

Before:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string Userid {
        get {
            return this.useridField;
        }
        set {
            this.useridField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Userid");
        }
    }
```

After:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public string Userid {
        get {
            return this.useridField;
        }
        set {
            this.useridField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Userid");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are any of the namespaces different?

Comment: Nope there are no namespace changes.

Comment: Are they different on the wire?

Comment: Coming across the wire the fields are all there but they are in a different order. For instance a subnode<ID> shows up 3rd from the top in one and 21st from the top in the other. They are still nested correctly.

Comment: The order must match. The name and namespace must match.

Comment: Ok, why is the order changing on me for no reason?

Comment: I have no idea. You would have to "ask" the code which is changing the order. Perhaps it isn't for "no reason". For instance, are the tags now in alphabetical order?

Comment: Also, "`[Policy]`"? Is this a WSE service?

Comment: Yes it is. The policy only enforces credentials on incoming requests.   "Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.UsernameOverTransportAssertion"

Comment: Were you aware that WSE is obsolete?

Comment: Yes, i am only modifying an existing and too complicated to replace web service.